# Selenium - How to perform cleanup when the browser is closed

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, selenium

I am working on a problem where i need to perform some cleanup before google chrome browser close button is clicked and the browser window is closed.

The cleanup involves **logging out of the website** and a few other things. Clearing out all cookies is not an option. Unfortunately I haven't come across any such examples where i could expose something like a shutdown hook (something similar to what exists in Java).

Does selenium provide any mechanism to override the close functionality so that i can perform the cleanup and then exit out of the browser when someone clicks on the close button or closes the browser?

**In short**

Due to some design related reasons i cannot do the cleanup when a test exits. Can i **hijack** the close button click (manual click)?

Comment: Can you elaborate what kind of actions are you planning by `cleanup`? How do you intend to use the `shutdown hook`?

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: `Logging out of the website` is not a part of `cleanup` operation. What else activities are you planning as `cleanup`?

Comment: By cleanup i meant, logging the user out and persisting some information back in a database. This is to ensure the next iteration can run on a brand new session.

Comment: `logging the user out` and `persisting some information back in a database` definitely both would be part of your `Tests` and can be done through Selenium. Anything else in `cleanup`?

Comment: Due to some design related reasons i cannot do the cleanup when a test exits. Can i hijack the close button click? Is that possible?

Comment: @AnkitRustagi when you say 'close button is clicked' are you doing this manually?

Comment: Yes. There is a scenario when the button is manually clicked which i want to handle as i had mentioned.

Comment: @AnkitRustagi Webdriver will not recognize a manually triggered event. Is there a specific point in code at which the manual closure will be done? If so then try to interact with the browser with any kind off click, webdriver will throw a UnreachableBrowserException which you can catch and do your stuff. This is based on Java, but javascript should have some similar exception.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up is a very broad description, it could involve and mean many things.

But usually when writing Selenium tests you want the state of the application to be resett after each test or each test suit.

This is usually done by `after` or `afterEach` methods. They run after each the complete set of tests or after each test. Just as you can set stuff up via the `before` and `beforeEach` methods.

How to logout, depends on your application. Could involve cleaning up a specific cookie/session or manually doing the steps a user would.

A short and broad example:

```
afterEach('Clear up', (done) => {
  driver
  .then(() => MyUtils.clearStorage(driver))
  .then(() => done());
});

after((done) => {
  driver
  .then(() => driver.quit())
  .then(() => done());
});
```

Comment: Due to some design related reasons i cannot do the cleanup when a test exits. Can i hijack the close button click?

Comment: Why would you not be able to use the `after` hooks?

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry about logging out of application if your browser is closed using selenium.

The browser which selenium launch does not store your history or cookies like normal browser. So in case if you have logged into the application using selenium and didn't log out, but simply closed the browser then in second attempt if you you open your application link using selenium then in this case also you have to provide the credential.

But in normal browser after login if you closed the browser and then again you open the browser and hit the application URL in browser then most of time you don't have to provide the credentials, it is automatically logged into application but this is not the case in Selenium.

Now by clean up if you meant to delete the data/record you have created using selenium then in this case you have to write code for deleting such record. Selenium won't delete its created record automatically.

Comment: I am using `user-data-dir` option to load my browser, so the cookies do persist

Comment: Just wanted to know whether you are facing any issues/discrepancies for using close() or quit() method? Or simply you want such solution for enhancement purpose?